# Time in android

Tags: android

In my android application I would like to block the user from changing the device time when my application is opened or minimised. The user should be able to change only once the app gets closed.

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why change device time at all??

Comment: Actually in my android app i would like to know how long is my app open so i thought i would take device time and by taking the difference i would get the time.So i dont want the user to change the time in the mean while.Any other way to get the time since the app is open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know how long is my app open so i thought i would take device time and by taking the difference i would get the time.

There is an API that will tell you how much time has passed since the device was booted, regardless of what the device clock is set to:

[`SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime%28%29) "returns milliseconds since boot, including time spent in sleep."

Answer (score 5):

1. Android applications do not get closed or minimized, they have different semantics.  Please read up on the activity life cycle.
2. Android applications do not get to block users from conducting other operations on the device.

Comment: Thanks Chris.Actually in my android app i would like to know how long is my app open so i thought i would take device time and by taking the difference i would get the time.So i dont want the user to change the time in the mean while.Any other way to get the time since the app is open?

Comment: since you started another question for that, please see the answer over there